# efficient way to find string with streamreader

Tags: c#

I get web response and use streamreader to obtain the response as a string

my code is

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

sample of string is

```
<div class="box-round">
<ol  style="list-style-type: decimal;list-style-position:outside;margin-left:42px;">
<li>Order ID #A123456 already exists: Update performed
</ol>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="box-round">
    <ol  style="list-style-type: decimal;list-style-position:outside;margin-left:42px;">
    <li>New order created
    </ol>
</div>
```

I want to locate the following line within the string

```
Order ID #A123456 already exists: Update performed
```

or

```
New order created
```

Is this the best way to search for the line(s)

```
  while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're parsing HTML?  Generally speaking, you should be using a HTML parser.  [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) could help you with that.

Comment: What type of efficiency are you looking for? ie Which resource are you concerned about minimising use of: memory, cpu or network?

Comment: With the powers to be I cannot use HTML Agility PAck

Comment: @Andy: I would look for min use of memory/cpu..

Answer (score 6):

Well, personally I would use:

```
string line;

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains(...))
    {
    }
}
```

Reading the line gives you the data *and* tells you whether you've reached the end of the stream. I agree with Jeff though - "parsing" HTML by reading it line by line is generally a bad idea. It *may* be good enough in your specific situation, of course.

Comment: @Jon: personally i think it's bad design but it is what is and I cannot change existing design..

Comment: @Mitch: While that happens to be true, it wasn't why I was up late last night - insomnia instead :(

Comment: ah, sorry to hear that Jon. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with regex, sure regex isn't the best method, but if this is a one time thing working with an html parser is probably more than you are bargaining for

```
Match myMatch = Regex.Match(input, 
       @"<div class=""box-round"">.*?<li>(.*?)</ol>", Regex.Singleline);

if (myMatch.Success)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This really depends - do you need to know where in the DOM your particular text resides?  How large is the input?  Will your string ever be split between two lines?

If you are only concerned about the presence of the text and your input is small enough to reside in memory, I'd just read the entire thing in to memory.  I'm not sure what the exact algorithm the CLR uses to do string matching, but some of the faster routines involve pre-processing both the query and the string to be searched, and having more information for the pre-processing could potentially yield a faster search.

Of course, this all depends on CLR internals and your particular requirements - test, test, test.

If you want to capture more information about your text and its relation to the surrounding document, I'd suggest looking at the [HtmlAgility](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library for parsing your document.