# Fastest way to find text in large online text file

Tags: c#, string, search

There's a url that contains only text.

It is in format of

`firstWord~:::~secondWord`

The goal is to look for the `secondWord` and then `Console.WriteLine` the `firstWord`.

If I had to guess, I would say to use `WebClient` to download the text file into a `string` and then look through it with `regex` to find it.

The issue is that this file is going to be around 1 gigabyte and I'm not sure what the fastest way of doing this is.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you want speed, then you'll definitely not want to use a regex

Comment: Perhaps you can download some data at a time? Say you have a method that reads until it finds a new line, then it processes that line of text in the way you want. If your text wasn't found, keep downloading a few bytes more until you find the next new line.

Comment: @VisualVincent That's a good point, but how long would it take if let's say the text is all the way at the bottom of the 1 Gig file.

Comment: That depends on your internet speed, your computer specs, and the way you write the code. You might want to do it in a separate thread/task as you are still downloading the entire 1 GB file, but only a few bytes at a time. It will most likely be faster downloading the file at first _(that is, if your string is at the bottom)_, but then again you must wait for the entire download to complete.

Comment: You could split it up into multiple threads/tasks too. For example if you get the entire file's size, then create four (4) tasks doing the same download and checking procedure, you can have each task download and process 1/4th of the file. This will make it go (very) roughly 4 times faster.

Comment: @VisualVincent But like why would this be faster, isn't it already going as fast as possible?

Comment: See folowing posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949997/efficient-way-to-find-string-with-streamreader

Comment: If you divide your work and have 4 tasks doing it instead of one, then of course it is faster. Think of it like four people examining a text. One person examining a long text will take time, but if there are four persons each examining 1/4th of the text, then they will do it approximetaly four times faster.

Comment: `isn't it already going as fast as possible?` - The only thing that can make an already fully speed-optimized process faster is by dividing the work. This is why we have multithreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the fastest method I can think of. That's not to say you can't shave a few ticks here and there... Happy for other feedback to see if we can streamline this any more.

```
// WebClient is very bulky with a lot of stuff we don't need.
// By dealing with the request, response and stream ourself we can get the string a bit faster.
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.UrlToDownloadStringFrom.com");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);

// the result should return "firstWord~:::~secondWord" as expected.
string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

// split the string apart whenever the string ~:::~ appears within it.
string[] resultSplit = result.Split(new string[] { "~:::~" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// resultSplit[0] is firstWord, resultSplit[1] is second word
string secondWord = resultSplit[1];
```

Comment: If `HttpWebRequest` is going to be much faster why is your example with `WebClient` also, the URL is going to contain more than just one iteration of `firstWord~:::~secondWord`. It's going to contain around 1 gig of text in that format with each line having different text

Comment: I read WebClient above. I have edited the answer to be as fast as I can think. I don't want to add checks in the stream reader because I think checking mid read will take longer than just letting it finish. But that is just my assumption, it would need testing.